# Изменить курсор при Drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-n-drop

Столкнулся с проблемой - пока не закончится перемещение, не применяются изменения курсора. Нужна помощь в решении.

```js
const base = document.getElementById('base');
const items = base.children;
let dragElement;
setListeners(items);

function handlerDragstart(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  target.style.cursor = 'move';
  dragElement = target;
}

function handlerDrop(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  base.insertBefore(dragElement, target);
  // dragElement.style.cursor = 'grab';
}

function setListeners(arrNodes) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrNodes.length; i++) {
arrNodes[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handlerDragstart);
arrNodes[i].addEventListener('dragover', handlerDragOver);
arrNodes[i].addEventListener('drop', handlerDrop);
  }
}

function handlerDragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#base{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.item{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: grab;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="base">
  <div class="item" draggable="true">0</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">1</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">2</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">3</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">4</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">5</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А нельзя было просто в CSS дописать `.item:active {cursor: move;}` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, Вы так сказали, буд-то это работает) У меня не выходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во время drag&drop нельзя ставить любой курсор.

Согласно [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect), могут быть только следующие значения:

- `copy` - A copy of the source item is made at the new location.
- `move` - An item is moved to a new location.
- `link` - A link is established to the source at the new location.

```js
const base = document.getElementById('base');
const items = base.children;
let dragElement;
setListeners(items);

function handlerDragstart(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  dragElement = target;
}

function handlerDrop(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  base.insertBefore(dragElement, target);
}

function setListeners(arrNodes) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrNodes.length; i++) {
    arrNodes[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handlerDragstart);
    arrNodes[i].addEventListener('dragover', handlerDragOver);
    arrNodes[i].addEventListener('drop', handlerDrop);
  }
}

function handlerDragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'link'; // ставим тип курсора
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#base {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: grab;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="base">
  <div class="item" draggable="true">0</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">1</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">2</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">3</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">4</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">5</div>
  <div class="item" draggable="true">6</div>
</div>
```